# Query not returning values

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So I'd like to think what I'm doing is fairly common. I'm attempting to display a result set using Django. I have looked online for a while and here is what I've come up with:

```
models.py{
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class SalesRep(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Sales(models.Model):
  seller = models.ForeignKey(SalesRep)  
  sold_on = models.DateField("Sold On")
}

sales_view.py{
from salesteam.models import SalesRep, Sales
from django.views.generic import ListView

class SellerHome(List View):
  model = SalesRep
  template_name = 'production/sales.html'

  @property
  def rep_sales(self):
    return Sales.objects.filter(SalesRep=self)
}

sales.html{
<div id="total-sales">
  {% for sale in SellerHome.rep_sales%}
    <li>{{ sale.id }}</li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>You don't currently have any sales</li>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
}
```

For the sake of completeness I even tried writing just the property out as `Sales.objects.all()` but still no luck. Thanks for taking a look as I'm fairly new to HTML, Django, and Python. Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: > Thanks for taking a look as I'm fairly new to HTML, Django, and Python. -- that is a lot to learn at once! o.O

Comment: @michaelb Yeahhhh, I had an opportunity to take an internship to learn HTML, Django, and python so I had to jump at it. At least Python and HTML haven't proven to be too difficult, Django is another story though -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what tutorial you've followed, but there is a lot of errors in your code... I'm assuming you would like to display all `Sales` for the logged in user?

In this scenario, I would change the model slightly to add a `related_name` to `Sales` foreign key to `SalesRep`:

```
class SalesRep(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Sales(models.Model):
  seller = models.ForeignKey(SalesRep, related_name='sales')  
  sold_on = models.DateField('Sold On')
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

And I would change the `views` to use `DetailView`:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class SellerDetailView(DetailView):
    model = SalesRep
    template_name = 'production/sales.html'
    context_object_name = 'seller'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Docs on DetailView — https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

```
<div id="total-sales">
    <ul>
    {% for sale in seller.sales.all %}
        <li>{{ sale.id }}</li>
        {% empty %}
        <li>You don't currently have any sales</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend avoiding class based views, at least as you are learning Django, since they are not really necessary and needlessly complicated for what you are doing.

Anyway, to answer your question using class-based views, your problem is in your template and your view. You'll want to put your rep_sales logic in a `get_queryset`, set the model to be Sales, not SalesRep, and then reference `object_list` in the template. [More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).

However, I'd instead recommend writing a normal, function-based Django view. Something like this might get you started:

```
def view_all_sales(request):
    my_sales_rep = SalesRep.objects.get(request.user)
    all_my_sales = Sales.objects.filter(seller=my_sales_rep)

    return render(request, "production/sales.html", {
        "sales": all_my_sales
    })
```